# Xcode Organizer - Devices showing yellow light

Tags: iphone

Got the developer certificate to test app on iphone entered device identifier, connected iphone as a device in the organizer it shows yellow light. In software version it shows 5.1 as installed on iphone device.  It displays that it does not match any of the versions of iOS supported for development with this installation of the iOS SDK. Please restore the device to a version of the OS listed below

Xcode Supported iOS Versions
Latest
5.0 (9A334)
4.3 (8F190)
4.3
4.2
4.1
4.0.2
4.0.1
4.0

Eventhough got latest version but still i restored iphone but still got yellow light not changing to green any idea how to fix this issue.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have Mac OS X Lion.

Apple no longer supports Snow Leopard as a development OS.  iOS 5.0 was the final version released on Snow Leopard.

It sounds like your iPhone has been updated to v5.1.  If you update your OS to Lion, you'll be allowed to install v5.1 of the iOS software from apple's developer website, and continue developing and testing your apps like normal.  Sorry to say though, this is impossible with Snow Leopard, which is why your organizer says "Please revert your iPhone iOS to v5.0, because that's the only thing I can support"

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick answer and helping me out. Appreciate it so much. Didn't realize that could be the reason but again thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey, no problem.  I had the same problem last week when a co-worker brought in an updated iPad.  v5.1 came out in early March, so it's still pretty new.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using xcode 4.2 and base SDK 5.0 than you **can't** test the app on your phone which has an OS version 5.1.

The general rule is that if you want your XCODE to detect the device for testing, the OS version on your phone should always be less than or equal to the base SDK (latest) supported by your XCODE.(And so should be the targeted OS version for the app)

Base SDK 5.1 is supported by XCODE 4.3 which only works on LION-X.

Hoping this helps.